# why is textarea larger in width and height than iframe?

Tags: html, css

I've got a textarea and an iframe, but the iframe is smaller than textarea:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- here's textarea: -->
  <textarea name="texta" id="texta" cols="30" rows="10" style="width: 200px;height:200px;"></textarea>
  <!-- here's iframe: -->
  <iframe src="" frameborder="2" style="width:200px;height:200px;"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

but if you run it, the iframe is smaller than the textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different padding and border.

Set them the same and they have the same size

```css
iframe, textarea {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- here's textarea: -->
  <textarea name="texta" id="texta"></textarea>
  <!-- here's iframe: -->
  <iframe src="" ></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Textarea has some `padding` added by a browser. To make it exactly `200px`, set the `box-sizing` property:

```css
textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

That will make your `textarea` exactly as wide as you want it to be.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set the height of your `iframe` to be equal to textarea. The fact is that when you set the width of any element, you actually set the width of its content and that doesn't include the paddings and border which that element may have. Also some elements have got their own preset paddings and border. To Overcome this problem you can set the `box-sizing` of your elements to `border-box`. This way you can set the whole width and height of your elements. I suggest you add the following property to your stylesheet to have all your elements border-boxed:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Also, in the following example, I have used flexbox. Look at the output and you will see it is exactly what you want:

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
iframe{
  height:170px;
}
textarea{
  height:170px;
  margin:0;
}
.container{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <textarea name="texta" id="texta" cols="30" rows="10" style="width: 200px;"></textarea>
  <!-- here's iframe: -->
  <iframe src="" frameborder="2" style="width: 200px;"></iframe>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: and if you want to support for some older firefox and some browsers add `-webkit-` or `-moz-`

Comment: oh! never knew that!